# Max file limit conundrum

Tags: launchd

Following [this](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X) article I've adjusted my open file limits:

```
$ launchctl limit
    maxfiles    65536          65536
```

The trouble with this is that when I try to open Adobe applications I get this error:

> Unable to set maximum number of files to be opened.

I'm not sure how to solve this. I need to increase my file limit but I also need to use Adobe products.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to mitigate the file limit. We ran into the same issue at our company with our platform team and were able to resolve the issue using the information below. [Source](http://blog.mact.me/2014/10/22/yosemite-upgrade-changes-open-file-limit)

1. Enter the following in Terminal:

   `$ echo kern.maxfiles=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   $ echo kern.maxfilesperproc=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   $ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65536
   $ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
   $ ulimit -n 65536 65536`
2. In `$HOME/.bash_profile` set the following: `ulimit -n 65535 unlimited`
3. Reboot system and try Photoshop again

Comment: Do you know which version of OSX you were using?

Comment: @jwerre we had to employ this on our Macs post-10.10.3, as the problem seemed to have occurred after an update in Yosemite. The same is true and applies for our El Capitan machines (all versions). For posterity's sake, please update your post as well with your OS, and I apologize for not checking w/ you first regarding which you were running

Answer (score 1):

On *El Capitan* and *Sierra*, I had created a `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` file to increase the max number of open files for use with [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) development. I had followed something like [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/827984/open-files-limit-does-not-work-as-before-in-osx-yosemite).

After I removed the file and rebooted, `ulimit -n` returns 256 (much lower than I need for *meteor*), but *Adobe Illustrator* now starts up fine!

Comment: Having modified my `maxfiles` too for another use, I couldn't start illustrator... disabling that mod allowed me to run illustrator again. Thanks for the tip!