# How to increase open file and max processes limit for Solr

Tags: macos, launchd, file, apache

I'm trying to run Apache Solr 8.8.1 on Ventura 13.0 and I get this warning:

```
$ ./solr-8.8.1/bin/solr start
*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 256.  
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption. 
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 2784. 
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption. 
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
```

I've tried `sudo launchctl limit maxproc 65000 4176` and `ulimit -u 65000`. The last command gives me the error `ulimit: value exceeds hard limit`.

I've also tried the answers here with no luck:

- [How to properly increase a `ulimit -n` limits?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/32235/477910)
- [Max file limit conundrum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224358/max-file-limit-conundrum)
- [How do I increase "ulimit -u" (max user processes)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77410/how-do-i-increase-ulimit-u-max-user-processes)

How do I increase my limits?